# Auth Email limits password reset in Firebase Free account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up a new application using Angular with Firebase. I'm using only Auth system. But like said in the Firebase docs, only 150 emails/day can be sent for Password reset.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#email_limits

I have two questions:

**1)** If a user spam the recover password button (that use the function *sendPasswordResetEmail()* ) does it consume this email limit ? If yes how to prevent that ?
(**Doc:** https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#sendpasswordresetemail )

**2)** Does the SMTP parameters (own server or other mail service) from Firebase project settings use the email limits ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 150 emails per day for passwords resets limit applies to emails sent through Google's mail servers. If requests are identified as spam, and email doesn't get sent, they don't count. If spam requests are not identified and email is sent, it does get counted. If you're running into spam problems and hit this (or other limits) because of that, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

The limit is on emails sent through Google's mail servers, if you use your own mail server, the limit doesn't apply.