# Rate limit in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am planning to use firebase authentication in my project. I am unable to find below in any documentation, Can someone help here?

1. Any way to rate limit per user
   Ex: only 10 forget password per day will be allowed. Or in case of password mismatch, only 10 attempt will be provided.
2. In case we have to migrate data from firebase to our own authentication system, what are the challenges?
   Thanks for help.

Comment: Those are two complete separate questions. Please make sure your posts ask a single question, so that they can be answered with a single answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717102/auth-email-limits-password-reset-in-firebase-free-account) . The tl;dr is no.
2. You can't. You can't get raw password out of Firebase, so that mean there is no way for you to migrate it to somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

1. Firebase already limits phone auth frequency for a number. You can only ask for 5 times per 4 hour(You can check it on your phone) . You don't have to do anything to limit.

Source:

https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52525587.html

2. Password hashing will be the main challenge. You can get Mobile number but not password.

Comment: There is way to get user data using auth:export (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth), But Even if we get this data ,How do we compare plain password with hashed password stored (done by firebase using modified scrypt algo), is there a way?